# Place elements in a wrapped div (custom locations)

Tags: html, css

I currently need to make a div similar to this : 
[image]

I tried to make a float left on my picture, but all my content on the right was on float right and i couldn't center or place it as I wanted. As you can see the elements need to be placed on the left or on the right. 
Here is what I already did :

```
<div class="container">
<div id="image">
        <img width="50%" height="50%" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/yJWb9F4zy-2hXiqojIvtlUeSsBrfnjF6FThB3ZZ6aR--YJjo1ftT4wB2u0f4Ob6yyw=w300">
</div>

    <div>
        <h2>Nom de l'activité</h2>
  <p id="right">4 participants | 1 place disponible </p>
  <p>Descriptif de l'activité</p>
  <p id="right"><strong>Prix</strong></p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Votre commentaire">


    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
#image{
  float: left;
}
#right{
  text-align: right;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWVWoZ)

Thank you in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`display:flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this - floating divs for positioning is no longer needed with css3.

Also you have a problem where you are setting the image to be 50% - as you have not set the width of your image div, it is causing the image div to take the full width of the image (before it is halved in sized), this is what is causing the large space on the right of the image.

You either need to give the image div a width and also either remove one of the width or height constraints otherwise your image may lose its aspect ratio

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}

#image {
  flex-basis: 150px;
}

#text {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#text>h2,
#text>p {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}

#text .right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="image">
    <img width="100%" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/yJWb9F4zy-2hXiqojIvtlUeSsBrfnjF6FThB3ZZ6aR--YJjo1ftT4wB2u0f4Ob6yyw=w300">
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    <h2>Nom de l'activité</h2>
    <p class="right">4 participants | 1 place disponible </p>
    <p>Descriptif de l'activité</p>
    <p class="right"><strong>Prix</strong></p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Votre commentaire">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it cancels all my text-align: right; everything is on the left now

Comment: See edit to the above, wasn't sure if you meant to have things aligned to the right

Comment: Thank you very much, that resolved my issue :-)
Have a great day !